# Performance implications of a large number of mutexes

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Suppose I have an array of 1,000,000 elements, and a number of worker threads each manipulating data in this array.  The worker threads might be updating already populated elements with new data, but each operation is limited to a single array element, and is independent of the values of any other element.

Using a single mutex to protect the entire array would clearly result in high contention.  On the other extreme, I could create an array of mutexes that is the same length as the original array, and for each element `array[i]` I would lock `mutex[i]` while operating on it.  Assuming an even distribution of data, this would mostly eliminate lock contention, at the cost of a lot of memory.

I think a more reasonable solution would be to have an array of `n` mutexes (where 1 < n < 1000000).  Then for each element `array[i]` I would lock `mutex[i % n]` while operating on it.  If `n` is sufficiently large, I can still minimize contention.

So my question is, is there a performance penalty to using a large (e.g. >= 1000000) number of mutexes in this manner, beyond increased memory usage?  If so, how many mutexes can you reasonably use before you start to see degradation?

I'm sure the answer to this is somewhat platform specific; I'm using pthreads on Linux.  I'm also working on setting up my own benchmarks, but the scale of data that I'm working on makes that time consuming, so some initial guidance would be appreciated.

---

That was the initial question.  For those asking for more detailed information regarding the problem, I have 4 multiple GB binary data files describing somewhere in the neighborhood of half a billion events that are being analyzed.  The array in question is actually the array of pointers backing a very large chained hash table.  We read the four data files into the hash table, possibly aggregating them together if they share certain characteristics.  The existing implementation has 4 threads, each reading one file and inserting records from that file into the hash table.  The hash table has 997 locks and 997*9973 = ~10,000,000 pointers.  When inserting an element with hash `h`, I first lock `mutex[h % 997]` before inserting or modifying the element in `bucket[h % 9943081]`.  This works all right, and as far as I can tell, we haven't had too many issues with contention, but there is a performance bottleneck in that we're only using 4 cores of a 16 core machine.  (And even fewer as we go along since the files generally aren't all the same size.) Once all of the data has been read into memory, then we analyze it, which uses new threads and a new locking strategy tuned to the different workload.

I'm attempting to improve the performance of the data load stage by switching to a thread pool.  In the new model, I still have one thread for each file which simply reads the file in ~1MB chunks and passes each chunk to a worker thread in the pool to parse and insert.  The performance gain so far has been minimal, and the profiling that I did seemed to indicate that the time spent locking and unlocking the array was the likely culprit.  The locking is built into the hash table implementation we are using, but it does allow specifying the number of locks to use independently of the size of the table.  I'm hoping to speed things up without changing the hash table implementation itself.

Comment: Which OS? I tried this once on CentOS with a prime of ~1M mutexes as opposed to a prime of ~1K mutexes (oh, BTW, use a prime), and there was a tremendous performance hit for a reason I never found out.

Comment: Plan A: lock the whole array.  You're right: this is simple ... but could result in high contention.  Plan B: Create and manage a mutex for each element.  Probably *not* a Good Idea...  SUGGESTION: Consider [read write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock), or "[RCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update)" locks: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h032u/index.html

Comment: @paulsm4 read/write locks are not helpful for this particular case, as I am building up a datastructure from my input files.  The data structure is essentially "write-only" at this point, so shared readers wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: @AmiTavory  This is AWS linux on an Amazon EC2 instance, so it should be fairly similar to CentOS.  My initial implementation used 997 mutexes.  So far, increasing to 9973 _seems_ to have reduced throughput rather than increasing it, but I'm still working on setting up useful performance tests.  Your experience matches my suspicion, but I would be curious to know why that is.

Comment: @Drew In any case, I think I'll share my (very partial) conclusions in the form of an answer.

Comment: A key question to the performance in this situation is, for how long would you lock the value you are working on?

Comment: @Drew If the data structure is "write-only", then what is the purpose of the mutex in the first place?  For example, if thread A writes 100 to array[0] and thread B writes 200 to array[0], does it matter whether the final array[0] contains 100 or 200?  If it matters, how does the mutex help to decide which value "wins"?

Comment: @JS1 It's 'write-only' in the sense that every access will result in modifying the array, so there's not a use case for a shared lock (aka read lock).  If multiple threads execute "array[0] += 2", it's true in a literal sense that they are both reading and writing, but from a synchronization perspective, each thread requires an exclusive lock, which is what I was referring to.

Comment: @Drew If a thread is executing "array[0] += 2", I would not say that the data structure is "write-only".  Now it is clear that the threads are reading from the array.  You could try a CAS (compare-and-swap) loop, where you attempt to atomically update an array element.  For example: (using GNU compiler) `__sync_fetch_and_add(&array[0], 2);`.  It should be faster than using mutexes, but you could measure the performance to be sure.

Comment: I would just like to point that there are almost always better ways to structure things than to have lots of threads all tightly fighting for access to the same collection. If we knew more about the types of objects in the collection and types of operations being done on them, we could probably come up with a solution that didn't have the threads fighting so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(A very partial & possibly indirect answer to your question.)

Have once scored a huge performance hit trying this (on a CentOS) raising the number of locks from a prime of ~1K to a prime of ~1M. While I never fully understood its reason, I eventually figured out (or just convinced myself) that it's the wrong question.

Suppose you have an array of length *M*, with *n* workers. Furthermore, you use a hash function to protect the *M* elements with *m < M* locks (e.g., by some random grouping). Then, using the [Square Approximation to the Birthday Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Square_approximation), the chance of a collision between two workers - *p* - is given by:

*p ~ n<sup>2</sup> / (2m)*

---

It follows that the number of mutexes you need, *m*, does not depend on *M* at all - it is a function of *p* and *n* only.

Comment: Under glibc `sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)` is 24, so your ~1M mutex array took up ~24M of memory, easily blowing your L3 cache and causing a lot of very slow misses to main memory.

Comment: (that's glibc on x86, other architectures will be different sizes).

Comment: Technically @caf answered the question as asked, but I'm going to mark this as the answer, because it answers the next question that I _should_ have asked.  Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 3):

Under Linux there is no cost other than the memory associated with more mutexes.

**However**, remember that the memory used by your mutexes must be included in your working set - and if your working set size exceeds the relevant cache size, you'll see a significant performance drop.  This means that you don't want an excessively sized mutex array.

As [Ami Tavory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30811756/134633) points out, the contention depends on the number of mutexes and number of threads, not the number of data elements protected - so there's no reason to link the number of mutexes to the number of data elements (with the obvious proviso that it never makes sense to have *more* mutexes than elements).

Answer (score 0):

In the general scenario, I would advise

- Simply locking the whole array (simple, very often "good enough" if your application is mostly doing "other stuff" besides accessing the array)

  ... or ...
- Implementing a read/write lock on the entire array (assuming reads equal or exceed writes)

Apparently your scenario doesn't match either case.

Q: Have you considered implementing some kind of a "write queue"?

Worst case, you'd only need *one* mutex.  Best case, you might even be able to use a lock-less mechanism to manage your queue.  Look here for some ideas that might be applicable: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx