# Parallel write to array

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a huge array of data where I need to read/write from/to random place from different threads. Having one `mutex` obviously will kill the performance. My idea is to have many `mutexes` each one is responsible for particular range in array. This way before writing I can lock a correct `mutex` based on index in array where I'm gonna to write. In theory it can reduce the race. But I wonder - maybe there's a better way?

Comment: If one worker read position A and later writes position B, how do you make sure either isn't changed in between, making the results meaningless? The reason I ask is because if there are access patterns, they might make a better approach possible, like e.g. a variation of the producer-consumer pattern, which is best solved using queues.

Comment: I can't be sure. The patterns are not known - it's some sort of depth buffer. That's why read and write should be done in a single lock.

Comment: I still don't understand: Do you read an element, perform some operation on it and then write back to that element? If that's the case, you could extract the algorithm that selects the elements and then distribute them via a simple producer-consumer queue to the worker threads and similarly pass them back to store the results.

Comment: "Do you read an element, perform some operation on it and then write back to that element?". Yes. Think about a depth buffer. I'm reading current depth for some pixel and if new depth is lower than current I need to write this new value. As you can imagine several threads can do the same for the single pixel simultaneously. I didn't get how can I distribute this value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds like a reasonable way to go.

There are a number of things to consider, though:

1. You state that your idea is to have "many mutexes, each one is responsible for particular range in array". You should probably consider the access patterns to decide how to assign entries to mutexes. If threads will tend to work on close-by entries, you might consider assigning entries to mutexes using a different scheme, e.g., the entry index modulo the number of mutexes.
2. From experience, note that the number of mutexes should be determined by the number of threads, not the range's size. I wrote on this more in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810999/performance-implications-of-a-large-number-of-mutexes) (it is the accepted answer, at the time of writing this).
3. Again depending on the usage pattern, you should consider using read/write locks to avoid needless serialization for multiple readers on the same entry. YMMV.

Comment: Just a small comment for "thing 1" - if threads work on nearby elements, one should be aware of [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing)

Comment: @AmiTavory Thanks. I really like this modulo thingy ).

Comment: @nikitablack You're very welcome! It's not that original, though - a standard hashing technique.